# Process Builder Not Firing Immediate Actions "On Create" For "Do you want to execute the actions only when specified changes are made to the record?"

Tags: process-builder, picklist, default-value, scheduled

I have a process builder for which I need immediate and scheduled actions to fire.  I have selected the option "Do you want to execute the actions only when specified changes are made to the record?" to allow the option to set Scheduled to appear in the Process Builder.

What I have noted is that if I make a change on the record to match the criteria for firing the actions it does so correctly. However on creating a record it does not fire if the criteria is met.  The PB has "when a record is created or edited" selected. The only thing I can think of is one of the fields in the criteria is a Picklist field. The Criteria is being met on create via the "default" option on the picklist field.  Could this be a factor (that the "default" value on a picklist does not appear to meet criteria as opposed to explicitly setting it in the record being created) or are Process Builders which have the "Do you want to execute the actions only when specified changes are made to the record?" option selected known not to fire on create?

Thanks in advance for any tips on this.

Answer (score 0):

Note for the above it turned out that the process builder was firing correctly for the immediate action also however it was an email alert and the email was not sending because the email alert is set to use the current users email address. Weirdly on the timebased email it does still send (even with the invalid email address) but it wouldn't on the immediate action.  All seems strange in a way with it firing on the timebased alert but changing the email address has fixed it for the immediate action. It might have been a coincidence somehow but that was the fix.